# Error with Lambda Function running on NodeJS netlify-lambda — "TypeError: Expected signal to be an instanceof AbortSignal"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, abort, airtable, netlify-function

I’ve recently been trying to set up a Lambda Function on a Netlify [site](https://www.hearthisidea.com). The rest of the site is running on Gatsby. I’m able to get some basic functions working in development and production (e.g. returning a “hello world”), but I’m running into a problem whenever I try something more complex.

My function always seems to return an error in development which says `Function invocation failed: TypeError: Expected signal to be an instanceof AbortSignal.` I haven’t tried getting it to work in production (although it obviously won’t work as it stands, relying on .env). I'm using [`netlify-lambda`](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda) for this.

For instance, here is the code I’m trying to get to work, lifted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gtalarico/e2114666e7fc38d5c144f7c514da687a). I'm trying to fetch records from a simple Airtable database using their API.

```
require("dotenv").config({ debug: process.env.DEBUG })


const Airtable = require("airtable")
Airtable.configure({
  endpointUrl: "https://api.airtable.com",
  apiKey: process.env.AIRTABLE_PASS,
})
var base = Airtable.base(process.env.AIRTABLE_ID)

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const allRecords = []
  base('Main')
    .select({
      maxRecords: 100,
      view: 'all'
    })
    .eachPage(
      function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
        records.forEach(function(record) {
          allRecords.push(record)
        })
        fetchNextPage()
      },
      function done(err) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err)
        } else {
          const body = JSON.stringify({ records: allRecords })
          const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: body,
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'cache-control': 'Cache-Control: max-age=300, public'
            }
          }
          callback(null, response)
        }
      }
    )
}
```

The error occurs whether I hit the url from my browser, or send a GET or POST request through Postman or a form.

The Netlify site name is affectionate-engelbart-b6885d, and the repo is [here](https://github.com/finmoorhouse/hearthisidea.com).

Happy to post error logs if that’s helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I am getting this same issue, It use to work in about June and I have made no code changes. Have you made any progress? I was thinking its something todo with AbortController and maybe how its hosted and a conflict with sub libs..

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade airtable to version  0.8.1.

I had the same issue. [I found this helpful](https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/issues/204).

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! I've been knocking my head against the wall for 3 days on this issue. Also, FWIW, there's a new addition to that thread which mentions override airtable's node-fetch dependcy here: https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/issues/204#issuecomment-1640828721